# Modifying lightbox plugin to allow for quoting, Does this exist?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, lightbox

I've been searching online for a plugin to use with my website that would allow the the user to click on an image in a foogallery image gallery and then have the image open in a fullscreen lightbox.

This itself is easy enough, but I would also like the user to be able to be able to click a toggle button and have a quote form that once filled and submitted would be sent to my email appear in the bottom third of the page.

Does anyone know of a plugin that allows this or that can be modified or am I out of luck? below is a mock up of what I'd like.

[image: Mockup]

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is no such plugin with the exact functionality you are looking for but you can try one of these plugins [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/sell-photos) to meet your requirements.